# Detecting Hardware of the Dyconn Dubbler Dock

Tags: linux-kernel, hardware-compatibility, usb-device, dock

I purchase USB3 dual-hard-drive docking station from Fry Electronics called the [Dyconn Dubbler Dock](http://www.dyconn.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.product_details&flypage=shop.flypage&product_id=87&Itemid=84).

When I plug this device into an Ubuntu Linux 15.04 laptop (kernel: 3.19.0-26-generic), I see no indication that I've plugged it in. When I plug it into a Windows 10 workstation, the hard drive (plugged into the dock) auto-mounts under "This PC" (drive E).

I know a few commands for hardware detection on Linux, but each command I know outputs the same output whether I have the device plugged in (and on) or not.

For example, with the device plugged in (and on, with a hard drive docked), I ran this command:

```
sudo lshw > ~/Desktop/hardware.txt
```

Then, with the device unplugged, I created another file like this:

```
sudo lshw > ~/Desktop/hardware2.txt
```

I used [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) to compare these two output-files, and they are identical.

Even if there are no Linux drivers for [this device](http://www.dyconn.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.product_details&flypage=shop.flypage&product_id=87&Itemid=84), I'd still like to report some information about the device to [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/), to help towards it eventually working with Linux. But none of the commands I know seem to detect its existence.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `lsusb -v` shows any difference after device added ?

Comment: Thanks Steve. Yes, that too showed no difference.